# How can i put textview inside edittext

Tags: java, android, android-layout

In WhatsApp when you reply to a message it shows like this:

[image: this]

I tried more times but I couldn't design layout like the one WhatsApp uses.

Comment: Use Relative Layout as parent layout, inside it make Linear layout and assign weights.

Comment: `How can i put textview inside edittext` you can't you can put views inside `ViewGroup` child classes. Edittext is not child calss of `ViewGroup`. Put them both in some layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need just inflate that text which is what you want to reply above your **EditText** view.My xml code is as below

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:orientation="vertical" 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/rl_resend_root_img"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/background">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Name"
                        android:id="@+id/tv_resend_name"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_resend_name"
                        android:text=" Photo"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        android:id="@+id/resend_no_cmnt"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/camera"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_resend_name"
                        android:text="what a pic brooo.."
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:id="@+id/resend_cmnt_data"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="36dp"
                        android:layout_height="36dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

            <ImageView
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:id="@+id/resend_image"
               android:src="@drawable/henna"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="top|end"
                    android:background="@drawable/background"
                    android:id="@+id/resend_clear_img"
                    android:src="@drawable/clear"/>
            </FrameLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

**Happy coding**